# Odoo v.13 - Configuring a gmail alias as outgoing mail

Tags: email, gmail, alias, odoo

I am trying to configure a gmail account as outgoing mail in Odoo ERP v.13.

The email supplied by the client is an alias of the original email.

When testing, Odoo indicates error "535" (incorrect user/password) when I use the alias, but when I use the original email, the test is correct.

Is there any way to configure the alias as outgoing mail?